# Is there any possibility to run a cron job with dynamic time interval ? Please suggest

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, whenever

Is there any possibility to run a cron job with dynamic time interval? Please suggest. I have used Ruby on rails, whenever .

Comment: Yes, Using webmin you can run a cron job with dynamic time interval.

Comment: Webmin is not something you should use just for dynamic time interval jobs.

Answer (score 2):

You might be looking for the `at` command. You can use `at` to trigger a `cron`-like event at a certain time.

Here are some examples:

```
$ echo "wget https://www.example.com" | at 11:45 jan 31
```

I believe this also works:

```
$ echo "wget https://www.example.com" | at now next week
```